# WinSock recv() timeout: setsockopt()-set value + half a second?

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock

I am writing a cross-platform library which, among other things, provides a socket interface, and while running my unit-test suite, I noticed something strange with regard to timeouts set via `setsockopt()`: On Windows, a blocking `recv()` call seems to consistently return about half a second (500 ms) later than specified via the `SO_RCVTIMEO` option.

Is there any explanation for this in the docs I missed? Searching the web, I was only able to find [a single other reference](https://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks.narkive.com/Xcon1xMl/recv-timeout-is-so-rcvtimeo-half-second) to the problem – could somebody who owns »Windows Sockets
Network Programming« by Bob Quinn and Dave Shute look up page 466 for me? Unfortunately, I can only run my test Windows Server 2008 R2 right now, does the same strange behavior exist on other Windows versions as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having the same problem. Going to use

patchedTimeout = max ( unpatchedTimepit - 500, 1 )

Tested this with the unpatchedTimepit == 850

Answer (score 2):

From [Networking Programming for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615799) by Jones and Ohlund:

> ### SO_RCVTIMEO optval
>
> ---
>
> - Type: int
> - Get/Set: Both
> - Winsock Version: 1+
> - Description : Gets or sets the timeout value (in milliseconds)
>     associated with receiving data on the
>     socket
>
> ---
>
> The SO_RCVTIMEO option sets the
>   receive timeout value on a blocking
>   socket. The timeout value is an
>   integer in milliseconds that indicates
>   how long a Winsock receive function
>   should block when attempting to
>   receive data. If you need to use the
>   SO_RCVTIMEO option and you use the
>   WSASocket function to create the
>   socket, you must specify
>   WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED as part of
>   WSASocket's dwFlags parameter.
>   Subsequent calls to any Winsock
>   receive function (such as recv,
>   recvfrom, WSARecv, or WSARecvFrom)
>   block only for the amount of time
>   specified. If no data arrives within
>   that time, the call fails with the
>   error 10060 (WSAETIMEDOUT). If the
>   receiver operation does time out the
>   socket is in an indeterminate state
>   and should not be used.
>
> For performance reasons, this option
>   was disabled in Windows CE 2.1. If you
>   attempt to set this option, it is
>   silently ignored and no failure
>   returns. Previous versions of Windows
>   CE do implement this option.

I'd think the crucial information in this is:

> If you need to use the SO_RCVTIMEO option and you use the WSASocket
>   function to create the socket, you
>   must specify WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED as
>   part of WSASocket's dwFlags parameter

I hope this is still useful :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, I'm using [`socket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742296(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `WSASocket()`, which sets the overlapped flag by default…

Answer (score -1):

your problem is not in **rcv** function timeout!

if your application have a while loop to check and receive just put an if statement to check the receive buffer last index for '\0' char to check is the receiving string is ended or not.

typically if rcv function is still receiving return value is the size of received data. size can be used as last index of buffer array.

```
   do{
       result = rcv(s,buf,len,0);
        if(buf[result] == '\0'){
           break;
        }
    }
    while(result > 0);
```

Comment: it called null terminated strings :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is completely off-topic here. My question was specifically about what happens in the timeout case, not about ways to avoid hitting a timeout in an application. As you point out, one shouldn't use a timeout to indicate the end of a transmission, but that's a matter of elementary network programming.