# Socket ReceiveTimeout

Tags: c#, sockets, timeout

I have specified the `ReceiveTimout` as 40 ms. But it takes more than 500ms for the receive to timeout. I am using a Stopwatch to compute the timetaken.

The code is shown below.

```
Socket TCPSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                              ProtocolType.Tcp);
TCPSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 40;

try
{  
    TCPSocket.Receive(Buffer);  

}  catch(SocketException e)  {  }
```

Comment: Please provide some more code.

Answer (score 12):

You can synchronously poll on the socket with any timeout you wish. If `Poll()` returns `true`, you can be certain that you can make a call to `Receive()` that won't block.

```
Socket s;
// ...
// Poll the socket for reception with a 10 ms timeout.
if (s.Poll(10000, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    s.Receive(); // This call will not block
}
else
{
    // Timed out
}
```

I recommend you read Stevens' UNIX Network Programming chapters 6 and 16 for more in-depth information on non-blocking socket usage. Even though the book has UNIX in its name, the overall sockets architecture is essentially the same in UNIX and Windows (and .net)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use timeout values which are less than 500ms.
See here for `SendTimeout`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendtimeout

Even though MSDN doesn't state the same requirement for the `ReceiveTimeout`, my experience shows that this restriction is still there.

You can also read more about this on several SO posts:

- [Setting socket send/receive timeout to less than 500ms in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785971/setting-socket-send-receive-timeout-to-less-than-500ms-in-net)
- [WinSock recv() timeout: setsockopt()-set value + half a second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234086/winsock-recv-timeout-setsockopt-set-value-half-a-second)

Answer (score 0):

I found this one:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 

IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect( sIP, iPort, null, null ); 

bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne( 40, true ); 

if ( !success ) 
{           

            socket.Close(); 
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to connect server."); 
}
```

Comment: I require the Receive to be synchronous not asynchronous. Also I do not want the socket to be closed if the Receive times-out.