# Socket receive timeout throws a delayed exception

Tags: c#, exception, timeout

In c#, I have a very simple server/client.  The client is set to timeout when receiving to 500 ms.  When it times out, I expect it to throw an exception and it does, however, I catch it 500ms later which totals up to a total second.  To double check that maybe I just have a slow machine, I test out how long it takes to throw an exception it it's about right.  Here are some snippets.

Server thread:

```
void ServerThreadProc()
{
    using (Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
        server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345));
        server.Listen(10);
        using (Socket accepted = server.Accept())
        {
            // Wait so long that client times out.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            accepted.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            accepted.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Testing receive timeout (fails):

```
public void ShouldNotExceedConnectionTime()
{
    Thread s = new Thread(ServerThreadProc);
    s.Start();
    using (var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 12345);
        byte[] buf = new byte[16];
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        try
        {
            watch.Start();
            client.Receive(buf);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            watch.Stop();
            Assert.That(ex.SocketErrorCode, Is.EqualTo(SocketError.TimedOut));
            Assert.That(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Is.AtLeast(475).And.AtMost(525));
        }
    }
    Assert.Fail("Should throw when timeout expired");
}
```

Results from the test:

> Result Message
>
> Expected: greater than or equal to 475 and less than or equal to 525
>
> But was:  1000

Testing throwing an exception (passes):

```
public void ThrowsInTime()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    try
    {
        watch.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        throw new Exception("Sleeping is done.");
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        watch.Stop();
        Assert.That(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Is.AtLeast(475).And.AtMost(525));
    }
}
```

Has anyone see an issue like this?

Comment: I suspect that there may have been some sort of protocol exchange that triggered a reset of the timeout. Have you tried sending data down the pipe, doing a receive to get that data, and then see what the timeout on the second receive is ?

Comment: Have you checked the value of the ReceiveTimeout property after connecting ?

Comment: I added your additional recommendations but unfortunately it still fails at 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several references ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234086/winsock-recv-timeout-setsockopt-set-value-half-a-second) and [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/recv-timeout-so-rcvtimeo-plus-half-second-help-26653302.html#)) to the underlying winsock implementation of the receive timeout may not quite work as expected. It may actually be implemented as about 500ms plus the value of the ReceiveTiemout property. Try setting the ReceiveTimeout to different values and see if the timeout is actually 500ms + the property value. If that is the case then you will need to account for the additional 500ms in your expected timeout calculations.

Comment: Yes, it's actually an addition of 500ms to the throw (i.e. a property of 750 results in 1.25 sec before I see the throw).  What's even more interesting is when I examine this in wireshark, I will see the last message and then a delay of the timeout plus 500ms before the FIN/ACK tcp message is sent.